# how to run shell script in background in unix

Tags: shell, unix

how to run shell script in background in unix?

My script

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    ps -fu $USER>>/home/axway/trace.log 2>&1 
    sleep 10
done
```

running above script (`shellEx1.sh`)  in background by `nohup` command on promt

```
nohup ./shellEX1.sh &
```

having below isuue:

```
$ nohup ./shellEX1.sh &
[3] 19520
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to    `nohup.out'
```

Comment: What is the problem? The script should work. Nohup is just giving you a warning ...

Answer (score 1):

Its warning to say like the output of the script will be written in file 'nohup.out'. In order to remove this warning, you can try

```
nohup ./shellEX1.sh >/tmp/output.txt &
```

or

```
nohup ./shellEX1.sh >/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you could make it connect or create a screen instance at the start.

`screen -S bashscript
my bash script`

Comment: That's not at all what the OP is asking, though.